# How to dynamically build a geoJSON with the results of an API call in javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have an API I am calling from, which returns the UK coordinate system coordinate pairs as so:

```
511062.800,171591.800
```

I have cleaned up the data, and transformed it into leaflet compatible coordinates using the following code:

```
function coordinatesTransformer(jsonData){

    const finalCleanedArray = jsonParser(jsonData);

    console.log(finalCleanedArray);

    for (var i = 0; i < finalCleanedArray.length; i++) {

        var x = finalCleanedArray[i].split(',');
        console.log(x);

        var p_wgs84 = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";

        var p_osgb = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs";

        transformer = proj4(p_wgs84, p_osgb);

        // transform coordinates to OSGB
        var xy = transformer.inverse([parseInt(x[0]), parseInt(x[1])]);
        console.log(xy);

        for (var j = 0; j < xy.length; j++){
            /*console.log(xy[j]);*/
            var lat = parseFloat(xy[0]);
            console.log(lat);
            var lon = parseFloat(xy[1]);
            console.log(lon);

            var geoJsonInit = {
                type: "FeatureCollection",
                features: []
            };

            var lonArray = [];
            var latArray = [];

            latArray.push(xy[j]);
            lonArray.push(xy[j+1]);

            console.log(latArray);
            console.log(lonArray);

            for (j in xy) {
                geoJsonInit.features.push({
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "LineString",
                        "coordinates": [lonArray, latArray]
                    }

                });
            }
            console.log(geoJsonInit);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try the code here:

```
 for (j in xy) {
                geoJsonInit.features.push({
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "LineString",
                        "coordinates": [lonArray, latArray]
                    }

                });
            }
```

The code does not seem to iterate through the lonArray or latArray like the previous code block has been doing. The console logs each value of the transformed coordinate pair, but I cannot seem to get the code to iterate when adding the coordinate values to the geoJson object.

This is the console.log screenshot, and if I scroll up the console.log, lines 236 and 237 show differing values based on the transformed coordinate pair, yet when I add them to the geojson you can see the coordinate pairs become the same:

[image: console.log] 
[image: console.log scrolled upwards]

Comment: Can you please add  `xy` object data to question

Answer (score 0):

> the coordinate pairs become the same

That is most probably an artifact from your browser console: when you expand your object to inspect it, it uses the value it has now, not the one it had when `console.log` was called.

Usually `JSON.stringify`-ing before displaying in console reveals this difference of behaviour.

Comment: When I stringify it gives me the same value as the floated integer just in [] like so `[51.43260384420582]`

Comment: My bad, looks like you just mix up your `j` index in embedded loop with outer loop.